# I want SIMBAD to treat the dash(hyphen) as a space

Tags: python, character-encoding, astroquery, simbad

I have a code using astroquery.Simbad to query star names. However Simbad working with names like "LP 944-20". However, the data contains names as "LP-944-20". How can i make code to ignore that first dash(hyphen)?

My code:

```
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
result_table = Simbad.query_object("LP-944-20", wildcard=True)
print(result_table)
```

Comment: Would the inputs always have the form of `X-Y-Z`?  Or, could there be other formats as well?

Comment: If there are more than 1 words, yes it has the form "X-Y" or "X-Y-Z". Otherwise, just "X"

Comment: Do you want `X-Y` to be treated as `X Y`?

Comment: Yes. I want to ignore just the first hyphen. "X-Y" as "X Y" or "X-Y-Z" as "X Y-Z"

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to just replace the first hyphen with space:

```py
inp = ["LP-944-20", "944-20", "20"]
output = [x.replace("-", " ", 1) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['LP 944-20', '944 20', '20']
```